# Android Studio not giving error on install of App on Vm

Tags: java, android, installation

I recently made my project, worked fine and the recently I've been getting the following error:

```
Installation failed due to: 'closed'
```

Any idea on how do I go about fixing this ?

If any extra info is needed I'll be glad to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your error carefully, it says `Installation failed due to: 'closed'`, closed what? the device on which you are running your application has been closed before the installation of your `Application`.
Now there are two possibilities:

1. If you are running it on `Physical Mobile Phone` then its might be a problem in your wire plugins
2. Or if running on `Virtual Machine` then Read this [Run apps on the Android Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator) and reinstall your `VM`.

and Also read this [Configure hardware acceleration for the Android Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration)

Comment: aah thanks this helped, I realized it was a problem with the wire plug-ins